# How to change order for pyramid plots with ggplot2 to dataset order?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have a dataset with climate suitability values (0-1) for tree species for both present and future.
I would like to visualise the data in a pyramid plot with the ggplot2 package, whereas present should be displayed on the left side of the plot and future on the right side and the tree species in the according order given in my raw dataset.

```
b2010<-read.csv("csi_before2010_abund_order.csv",header=T,sep = ";")

str(b2010)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ species: Factor w/ 10 levels "Acer platanoides",..: 9 9 7 7 8 8 6 6 5 5 ...
 $ time   : Factor w/ 2 levels "future","present": 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ grid1  : num  0.6001 0.5945 0.6366 0.0424 0.6941 ...
 $ grid2  : num  0.6399 0.5129 0.6981 0.0399 0.711 ...
 $ grid3  : num  0.6698 0.5212 0.6863 0.0446 0.6795 ...
 $ mean   : num  0.6366 0.5429 0.6737 0.0423 0.6949 ...
 $ group  : Factor w/ 1 level "before 2010": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

b2010$mean = ifelse(b2010$time == "future", b2010$mean * -1,b2010$mean)
head(b2010)
            species    time      grid1      grid2      grid3        mean       group
1    Tilia europaea present 0.60009009 0.63990200 0.66975713  0.63658307 before 2010
2    Tilia europaea  future 0.59452874 0.51294094 0.52115256 -0.54287408 before 2010
3 Sorbus intermedia present 0.63659602 0.69813931 0.68629903  0.67367812 before 2010
4 Sorbus intermedia  future 0.04242327 0.03990654 0.04460707 -0.04231229 before 2010
5     Tilia cordata present 0.69414478 0.71097034 0.67950863  0.69487458 before 2010
6     Tilia cordata  future 0.55790818 0.53918493 0.51979470 -0.53896260 before 2010

ggplot(b2010, aes(x = factor(species), y = mean, fill = time)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_share(~time, dir = "h", scales = "free", reverse_num = T) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Now, future and present are in the wrong order and also the species are ordered alphabetically, even though they are clearly "factors" and should therefore be ordered according to my dataset. I would very much appreciate your help.
Thank you and kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how factors work. Bars are plotted in the order as printed by `levels(b2010$species)`. In order to change this order, you'll have to manually reorder them, i.e.

```
b2010$species <- factor(b2010$species, 
                        levels = c("Sorbus intermedia", "Tilia chordata"...))
```

These levels can naturally be also a function of some statistic, i.e. mean. To do that, you would do something along the lines of

```
myorder <- b2010[order(b2010$mean) & b2010$time == "present", "species"]
b2010$species <- factor(b2010$species, levels = myorder)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I could adjust the order manually based on your answer. Yet, I was wondering if there is a faster method, because the order in my dataset is already correct and it is obviously more work to specify the factor and typing all species names again.

Comment: You just need to pass it a vector of character names. Perhaps you could do `myorder <- b2010$species[b2010$time == "present"]` would already work?